# How to scrape images from webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Please pardon my ignorance but I can't get my head around this. I had to create a new question as I have realized that I don't really know how to do this. So how to scrape the images from the webpage like this https://www.jooraccess.com/r/products?token=feba69103f6c9789270a1412954cf250 ? I have an experience with BeautifulSoup but as far as I understand, I need to use some other package here? `soup.find("div", class_="PhotoBreadcrumb_...6uHZm")` doesn't work

```
<div class="PhotoBreadcrumb_PhotoBreadcrumb__14D_N ProductCard_photoBreadCrumb__6uHZm">
   <img src="https://cdn.jooraccess.com/img/uploads/accounts/678917/images/Iris_floral02.jpg" alt="Breadcrumb">

<div class="PhotoBreadcrumb_breadcrumbContainer__2cALf" data-testid="breadcrumbContainer">
    <div data-position="0" class="PhotoBreadcrumb_dot__2PbsQ"></div>
    <div data-position="1" class="PhotoBreadcrumb_dot__2PbsQ"></div>
    <div data-position="2" class="PhotoBreadcrumb_dot__2PbsQ"></div>
    <div data-position="3" class="PhotoBreadcrumb_dot__2PbsQ"></div>
    <div data-position="4" class="PhotoBreadcrumb_active__2T6z2 PhotoBreadcrumb_dot__2PbsQ"></div>
    <div data-position="5" class="PhotoBreadcrumb_dot__2PbsQ"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is already a question from you on the subject, which has already received answers that point to the problem or show an alternative. [How to scrape images from slider/slideshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299993/how-to-scrape-images-from-slider-slideshow)

Comment: If it is not a duplicate, **what is the difference**? Suggestion - Take a minute or two to read [ask] and improve your question with a [mcve] . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is for cleaning the html gotten after sending http request, in your case you should :

**1.** Send *http request* to your target website with `requests` module. (with appropriate headers).

**2.** Select the json data of the response.

**3.** Iterate over the list of products.

**4.** For each product get the img_urls .

**5.** Send a new request to get each image in your list of urls.

**6.** Save the image.

---

**Code** :

*Note* : you should update the cookie in the headers to get a response.

```
import requests
from os.path import basename
from urllib.parse import urlparse

URL = 'https://atlas-main.kube.jooraccess.com/graphql'
headers = {"accept": "*/*","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br","Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7","Connection": "keep-alive","Content-Length": "2249","content-type": "application/json","Cookie":"_hjSessionUser_686103=eyJpZCI6ImY4MTZjN2YxLWJlYmQtNTg2ZC1iYmRkLTllYjdhNGQzNmVjYiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDYxMTkwMDUyODcsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _hjSession_686103=eyJpZCI6ImM5MWJmOGRhLTcwZDEtNGQ2ZS04MzA1LTQ4NWNlYTYzZGMwNSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDYxMjc3MDQ5MjgsImluU2FtcGxlIjp0cnVlfQ==; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; mp_2e072c90929b30e1ea5d9fd56399f106_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217f4456c057375-062236d0c47071-a3e3164-144000-17f4456c05857f%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2217f4456c057375-062236d0c47071-a3e3164-144000-17f4456c05857f%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22accountId%22%3A%20null%2C%22canShop%22%3A%20false%2C%22canTransact%22%3A%20false%2C%22canViewAssortments%22%3A%20false%2C%22canViewDataPortal%22%3A%20false%2C%22userId%22%3A%20null%2C%22accountUserId%22%3A%20null%2C%22isAdmin%22%3A%20false%2C%22loggedAsAdmin%22%3A%20false%2C%22retailerSettings%22%3A%20false%2C%22assortmentPlanning%22%3A%20false%2C%22accountType%22%3A%201%7D","Host": "atlas-main.kube.jooraccess.com","Origin": "https://www.jooraccess.com","Referer": "https://www.jooraccess.com/","sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0","sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows","Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty","Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors","Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site","User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36",}
result = requests.get(URL, headers ).json() # you may need headers argument so you should add it in this case

data = result["data"]["public"]["collectionProductsByShareToken"]["edges"]

for d in data:
  img_urls = d["product"]["imageUrls"]
  for img_url in img_urls:
    img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
    img_name = basename(urlparse(img_url).path)
    with open(img_name , 'wb') as handle:
      response = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)

      if not response.ok:
        print(response)

        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
          if not block:
            break

          handle.write(block)
```

Comment: Source for save the image : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url

Comment: thanks for the response but it doesn't work, when I view the "page" after executing page = BeautifulSoup(result.content, features='html.parser') I don't even see the same html code that I see when I click 'Inspect' in Chrome, this one is much shorter and doesn't even contain 'img' or 'src'

Comment: After reviewing your case, I found that the site send the data in json format (graphql behind the scenes), but there are multiple products and each have a list of image urls, want you get all of the images or what ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, sudoer Ali! Yes, ideally I'd like all of the images

Comment: Check the new version of code now, you should update the cookie in the headers.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me but for some reason this still doesn't work for me, either I'm copy-pasting wrong cookies or not formatting it correctly